# How to reverse engineer a database and generate code using spring boot and jOOQ?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jooq

### Introduction

After reading some blogs and watching some presentations on jOOQ, I got really excited to try out the reverse engineering api and replace the current hibernate tool I am using to reverse engineer a database.

Based on the example configuration by Petri Kainulainen http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-configuration/ and the spring boot friendly adaptation from the founder of jOOQ https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example, I have tried to setup a spring-boot-starter-jdbc with the goal of generating POJO's from a mysql database (sakila example from the MySQL website).

When running the program using mvn clean install and/or just run it as a spring boot application no code generation happens. Standard spring boot application runs and no errors and/or warnings are shown.

```
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:50.604[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mn.sander.mieras.application.Application [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Application on MacBook-Pro-van-Sander.local with PID 628 (/Users/Sander/Development/Workspace/reverse-engineer-jooq/target/classes started by Sander in /Users/Sander/Development/Workspace/reverse-engineer-jooq)
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:50.606[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mn.sander.mieras.application.Application [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:50.641[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@11e21d0e: startup date [Mon May 23 14:07:50 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:51.451[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:51.460[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mn.sander.mieras.application.Application [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Application in 1.036 seconds (JVM running for 1.66)
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:51.461[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[       Thread-1][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@11e21d0e: startup date [Mon May 23 14:07:50 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-05-23 14:07:51.463[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m628[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[       Thread-1][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

### Given

The pom.xml build configuration as taken from the jOOQ-spring-boot-example with some adjusted configuration (some standard dependencies omitted for readability)

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <files>
                        <file>src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
                      </files>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>                     
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>reverse-engineer</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                                <url>${db.url}</url>
                                <user>${db.username}</user>
                                <password>${db.password}</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <database>
                                    <name>${jooq.generator.db.dialect}</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes></excludes>
                                    <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
                                    <inputSchema>SAKILA</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <generate>
                                    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                                    <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                                    <pojos>true</pojos>
                                    <records>true</records>
                                </generate>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>nl.sander.mieras.domain</packageName>
                                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>           
                <dependencies>                  
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>                      
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>             
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>  
</build>
```

And given my main configuration class looks like this (all the beans code is taken from the jOOQ-spring-boot-example):

```
@Configuration
// not sure if I need this setting since I initialize it in the pom build
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") 
@Import({SpringTransactionProvider.class, ExceptionTranslator.class})
public class JooqSpringBootConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;    

    @Autowired
    private SpringTransactionProvider txp;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionTranslator ext;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword("db.password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException{
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DSLContext dsl(org.jooq.Configuration config){
        return new DefaultDSLContext(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionProvider connectionProvider(DataSource dataSource){
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecuteListenerProvider executeListenerProvider(ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator){
        return new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(ext);
    }

    @Bean
    public org.jooq.Configuration jooqConfig(ConnectionProvider connectionProvider, TransactionProvider transactionProvider, ExecuteListenerProvider executeListenerProvider){

        return new DefaultConfiguration()
                .derive(connectionProvider)
                .derive(txp)
                .derive(executeListenerProvider)
                .derive(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    }

}
```

And last but not least the application.properties file in the source/main/resources directory:

```
#Database Configuration
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SAKILA?useSSL=false
db.username=root
db.password=****

#jOOQ Configuration
jooq.generator.db.dialect=MYSQL
```

### Question

Given above configuration, what configuration did I miss/and or misconfigured to enable code generation (e.g. POJO's) ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to my problem based on the example from https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/springboot-tutorials/tree/master/springboot-jooq-demo

All I needed was a well configured pom and no actual java code was needed.

Just by using **clean install with profile reverse** it generates the code that I want.

The pom (the plugin inside the profile with id "reverse"):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>                           
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <jdbc>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila</url>
            <user>root</user>
            <password>****</password>
        </jdbc>
    <generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
         <database>
             <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
             <includes>.*</includes>
             <excludes />
             <inputSchema>sakila</inputSchema>
         </database>
    <generate>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>      
        <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>  
        <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>     
        <instanceFields>false</instanceFields>   
        <records>false</records>            
        <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
        <relations>true</relations>
        <globalObjectReferences>false</globalObjectReferences>
        <pojos>true</pojos>                                 
    </generate>
    <target>
        <packageName>nl.sander.mieras.domain</packageName>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </target>
    </generator>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the application:

```
package nl.sander.mieras.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated to:

- SpringBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE
- JOOQ 3.12.1
- PostgreSQL 9.6

*Maven Command:* **mvn clean install -Preverse**

#### *Application.properties*

```
#Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-database
spring.datasource.username=db-user
spring.datasource.password=db-password
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
#jOOQ Configuration
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=POSTGRES
```

#### Maven *pom.xml*

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jooq.version>3.12.1</jooq.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--JOQQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JOQQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>reverse</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/avro</url>
                                <user>avro</user>
                                <password>avro</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <name>org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator</name>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                                    <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes/>
                                </database>
                                <generate>
                                    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                                    <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
                                    <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>
                                    <instanceFields>false</instanceFields>
                                    <records>false</records>
                                    <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
                                    <relations>true</relations>
                                    <globalObjectReferences>false</globalObjectReferences>
                                    <pojos>true</pojos>
                                </generate>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>com.example.domain</packageName>
                                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

#### *JOOQ Configuration class*

```
@Configuration
@Import({SpringTransactionProvider.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JooqSpringBootConfiguration {

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public JooqSpringBootConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException {

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnectionDataSource() {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
        return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyConnectionDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(lazyConnectionDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer() {
        return new JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

        jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
        jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(
                jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()
        ));

        String sqlDialectName = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.jooq.sql-dialect");
        SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(sqlDialectName);
        jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

        return jooqConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }
}
```